# Weird mysql beahviours with timezones? How to control them?

Tags: java, timezone

I wrote a webapp using spring+hibernate. I developed everything on windows and then I moved it to a Linux virtual server (Aruba, an Italian provider). I noticed an annoying thing: when dates where saved on windows the time would be the same of my "wall clock", so if I read 13:45 I will have the same hour in the mysql row. This doesn't happen on Linux anyway. In fact the linux machine is on CEST as well (my timezone), I got it typing "date" in the shell. But I get the dates saved in the DB with an offset that is relative to GMT. Again, my app always displays everything in GMT (Including GMT as a time zone if I choose to format the dates to display the time zone) and mysql saves everything in that format. How do I control all this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post the solution by myself, because I think it's worth having it in this site.

First of all: mySql doesn't store any timezone information. So say that you are running on GMT+4 and you write a couple of records that contain date fields. Then you move your system in GMT-2 you read those records (perhaps importing the data from mysqldump). If your system and VM have GMT-2 as timezone the dates you read will be taken as if they were written in GMT-2 and NOT ADJUSTED.

Solution: **Take control of your VM timezone** by using  `-Duser.timezone="GMT"` command line option (you can even put this in your Tomcat startup script) or your preferred timezone (but GMT is better, let me explain why). This way you'll know **for sure** which timezone your VM is running. This **doesn't mean that Java VM will assume that your system time is the one you specified in your user.timezone**, it will know the system timezone and adjust dates accordingly. In fact if you are not in GMT, you will see dates in adjusted to GMT and saved to DB accordingly. This way you'll be sure that you are using that as a reference.

The problem is that if you take a date object and you do `myDateObject.toString()`, you'll get the date adjusted to GMT, with the hour offset. Which is not what you'll probably want.

The solution is to use `SimpleDateFormat` and do somthing like this when you have to output a date:

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "HH:mm   dd/MM/yyyy z", Locale.ITALY);

        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Rome"));
```

Everything will get converted the right way. You can even go further if you are developing a web app. You can extract the timezone from the HttpRequest and adjust date output accordingly, but I didn't go so far as I'm writing an application that is intended for Italian users only :D (yay).

Hope this will help.